# CUBESET containing multiple conditions in EXISTS function

Tags: excel, mdx, excel-2013

I'm trying to create a Cubeset that filters on 2 columns, and excludes a certain value. I can get it to work fine if just filtering on a single column like:

```
=CUBESET("DataSource","EXCEPT(EXISTS([Data].[CustomerName].children, {[Data].[ResolvedByName].&["&$A$1&"]}),{[Data].[CustomerName].&})","",2,"[Measures].[Number of Tickets Resolved]")
```

This brings back a set of customer names ordered by Number of Tickets Resolved, excluding tickets that have a blank customer name, and only where the person resolving is equal to the value in cell A1.

I want to tweak this so it also filters where resolving month is equal to the value in cell B3. According to all the examples that I can find, it should be as simple as this:

```
=CUBESET("DataSource","EXCEPT(EXISTS([Data].[CustomerName].children, {[Data].[ResolvedByName].&["&$A$1&"], [Data].[ResolvedMonth].&["&B$3&"]}),{[Data].[CustomerName].&})","",2,"[Measures].[Number of Tickets Resolved]")
```

however this does not work and I can't figure out for the life of me why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the `{` and `}` characters to `(` and `)` it should work.

The problem is that the curly brackets indicate a set but a set must have members of the same hierarchy. The parenthesis indicates a tuple which has one member of different hierarchies.

Comment: What about the additional ampersands at the end of some of the expressions - are they ok to include?

Comment: @whytheq `[Data].[CustomerName].&` just means the key is null.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response - this worked fine for me!